# React Submenu Toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submenu, next.js

I have a Mobile Menu Component that I'm populating with data from my custom WP-API menu route. This returns each menu item as an object in an array, as well as nests an array of child objects with each menu item if there is a submenu.

Check it out here:
https://www.digitalreactor.co/wp-json/menus/v1/menus/header-menu

I'm trying to create a toggle for this but I'm having trouble working out the details.

Project Specs:

React/Next.js

Here's my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { SortDown } from "styled-icons/fa-solid/SortDown.cjs";
import SubMenu from "./SubMenu";

class MobileMenu extends Component {

getSlug(url) {
        const parts = url.split("/");
        return parts.length > 2 ? parts[parts.length - 2] : "";
    }

render() {
  function uniqId() {
            return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
                var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
                return v.toString(16);
              });
        }
}
  const menuItems = this.props.menu.map((item, index) => {
     const slug = this.getSlug(item.url);
     const uniq = uniqId();
            const actualPage = item.object === "category" ? "category" : "page";
            if (item.children) {

                return (
                        <li>
                            <Link prefetch
                                as={`/${slug}`}
                                href={`/${actualPage}?slug=${slug}&apiRoute=${item.object}`}
                                key={item.ID} 
                                remove
                            >
                                <a style={linkStyle}>{item.title}</a>
                            </Link>
                            <SortDown onClick={() => {document.getElementById(uniq).style.display = "flex";}}/>
                            <SubMenu id={uniq} location="mobile" parent={slug} menu={item.children}/>
                        </li>
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <li>
                        <Link prefetch
                            as={`/${slug}`}
                            href={`/${actualPage}?slug=${slug}&apiRoute=${item.object}`}
                            key={item.ID} 
                            remove
                        >
                            <a style={linkStyle}>{item.title}</a>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                );
            }
  });

}
```

So as you can see I'm taking the api and pushing the children into the SubMenu component and that's working great. In the submenu I have that component set to display: none. With this example I'm able to open the submenus but no matter what I've tried I can't get the submenu to work as a toggle.

I've tried to set state but that wouldn't work for me. It kept returning null because the component would rerender and my unique IDs would be changed.

I tried to set shouldComponentUpdate to false but then nothing would happen at all.

I know I'm very close so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a quick note. I've simplified this slightly but the code is working. I'm using styled-components but I decided to show this example without them.

Comment: too many things missing (SubMenu) but if you want to mark (toggle) link as active you must compare with current page, no matter on this or deeper (SubMenu) level